# How to restart the PC in the first execution vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that makes some changes in Windows , some of these changes require Windows restart to take effect . So , my question is : How can i restart the computer only for the first tool execution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep restart option in the registry. Depending on the type of changes you make, use either `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` \ Software \ your brand \ your program \ create a DWORD key called RestartRequired.

If you have installation process, you can initially create this key with a value of 1. Then set to 0 just before closing and doing the restart. If you don't install anything, you can check whether RestartRequired=0 exists in the registry at a certain location. If it does not, it will create this value and commence restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in file if changes are made. Then you can check this file if restart occured.

Comment: Yea I will create a txt file , then in form load i will add a command to check for the file , if it exist then a restart has been